# How to sanitize and validate user input login in struts 1.3 to pass a Checkmarx scan

Tags: security, code-analysis, struts-1, static-code-analysis, checkmarx

I launched checkmarx on my web project based on `Struts 1.3`, it returns me this error:

Method execute at line xxx of `...\action\AbstractAction.java` gets user input for the form element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method %> at line 1 of `../xx.jsp` . This may enable a Cross-Site-Scripting attack.

How do I properly sanitize or validate properly to satisfy Checkmarx?

Answer (score 3):

Just encode the value beforeyou print it inthe JSP page. There are a number of different encodings used for different scenarios. Google "OWASP xss prevention cheat sheet".
Checkmarx is familiar with ESAPI encoders..

Comment: are you have an example with configuration for an implementation of ESAPI encoders.